# Python simultaneously loop, enumerate, and add to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Is there a neat way to loop through a list, adding the value as a dictionary key, and its position in the list as its value?
something like:

```
for x,y in enumerate(line):
    dictItem[x] = y
```

but in one line?

Comment: Does the dictionary already contains elements?

Comment: `value as a dictionary key, and its position in the list as its value` OR `position in the list as key and value as element itself`?

Comment: `dict(enumerate(line))` should yield a dictionary you need

Comment: @khelwood or even `dict(enumerate(line))`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Good point.

Comment: Thanks all for the quick responses, dict(enumerate(line)) works great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply feed the enumerate to the `dict` constructor:

```
dictItem = dict(enumerate(line))
```

`dict(..)` can construct a dictionary when you give it an *iterable* of 2-tuples that contain the *key* and the *value*. Your `enumerate(..)` generates tuples with that key and value.

In case you want to **update** the dictionary (i.e. add new values or update the existing ones), you can write:

```
dictItem.update(enumerate(line))
```

Comment: Awesome,  nailed it.

Comment: My thought too, but actually think the OP wants to update the `dict` not create a separate one for each item

Comment: Modified. Thanks to both.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
dictItem.update(enumerate(line))
```

For example:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a.update(enumerate([4, 5, 6]))
>>> a
{0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 6}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
{pos:val for pos,val in enumerate(line)}
```

Exicution,

```
In [6]: line = [7,6,5,4,4]    
In [7]: {pos:val for pos,val in enumerate(line)}
Out[7]: {0: 7, 1: 6, 2: 5, 3: 4, 4: 4}
```